# overlapping of image in QT

Tags: qpainter, qimage, qt4.8

I have a two images. I need to super impose/overlap the image on one another. The first image or base image is of the size say 160x128, let the second image be 120x100. How do I overlap each other?

Here is my code, I took this as a ref :

https://idvlpsw.wordpress.com/2008/03/19/use-qimage-to-create-a-composite-image-ie-one-image-with-another-overlaid-on-top-of-it/

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QFile>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>


QLabel *lbl= NULL ;

QImage baseImage("/usr/image1.jpg");
QImage overlayLogoff("/usr/image2.jpg");


QImage createImageWithOverlay(const QImage& baseImage, const QImage& overlayImage)
{
    QImage imageWithOverlay = QImage(baseImage.size(), QImage::Format_RGB16);
    QPainter painter(&imageWithOverlay);

    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
    painter.fillRect(imageWithOverlay.rect(), Qt::transparent);

    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, baseImage);

    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);
    painter.drawImage(0, 0, overlayImage);

    painter.end();

    return imageWithOverlay;
}

QImage logoffImage = createImageWithOverlay(baseImage, overlayLogoff);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    lbl = new QLabel();

    createImageWithOverlay(baseImage, overlayLogoff);
return a.exec();
}
```

Here I am unable to get any image ? Do I need to use show function to display image.

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I imagine you're trying to display the composite image in the QLabel.
But for this code to work, the composite image must be attached to the QLabel, and the QLabel itself must be made visible:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   QLabel * lbl = new QLabel();
   QImage composite = createImageWithOverlay(baseImage, overlayLogoff);
   lbl->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(composite));
   lbl->show();

   return a.exec();
}
```

PS: you should try avoiding defining variables in the global scope as much as possible.